# can't edit a bundle product after adding to cart from product list page

Tags: bundle, edit, kabel-bundleplus

I'm using kable-bundleplus module and I've added the add to cart button at the product list page for my bundle products which have default values using this code:

```
<?php
$productAddUrl = $this->helper(‘checkout/cart’)->getAddUrl($_product);
if ($_product->getTypeId() == ‘bundle’):
$bundleOptions = ‘?';
$selectionCollection = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection($_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($_product), $_product);
foreach($selectionCollection as $option):
$bundleOptions .= ‘&bundle_option[‘ . $option->option_id . ‘]=’ . $option->selection_id;
$bundleOptions .= ‘&bundle_option_qty[‘ . $option->option_id . ‘]=’ . $option->selection_qty;
endforeach;
$productAddUrl .= $bundleOptions;
endif;
?>
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__(‘Add to Cart’) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation(‘<?php echo $productAddUrl ?>’)"><span><span><?php echo $this->__(‘Add to Cart’) ?></span></span></button> <?php else: ?>
```

I got it from here 
http://understandinge.com/forum/all-things-coding/add-a-bundle-product-to-cart-from-category-page/

everything is working fine, the product is added to the cart with the correct default options with default quantities. But when I press edit from the shopping cart page I see all the options has the default quantity value and I'm getting script errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'customQty' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reloadPrice' of undefined
```

and when I press on the checkbox to change quantity I'm getting this one

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'changeSelection' of undefined
```

I think the problem is in the url used to add the product to cart but I'm not sure how.

any help?

Answer (score -1):

I've fixed it and here is the solution in case if anyone is interested

replace the two lines

```
$bundleOptions .= ‘&bundle_option[‘ . $option->option_id . ‘]=’ . $option->selection_id;
$bundleOptions .= ‘&bundle_option_qty[‘ . $option->option_id . ‘]=’ . $option->selection_qty;
```

with

```
$bundleOptions .= '&bundle_option[' . $option->option_id . '][0]=' . $option->selection_id;
$bundleOptions .= '&bundle_option_qty[' . $option->option_id . ']['.$option->selection_id.']=' . $option->selection_qty;
```

Comment: I've got this same problem. Where can i find the file where this code is located? Thanks in advance!